# Deploy pretrained model to simple web app

Tags: deep-learning, predictive-modeling, image-classification

As a small personal project, I wanted to try and deploy [this image classification model](https://github.com/nyukat/breast_cancer_classifier) with a simple web app (input image, output classification and heatmap). There are a couple pretrained models on that link. What is the absolute easiest way to do this (don't need production level capabilities)?

Answer (score 1):

Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

It's a Python framework for dynamic web resources. Should be reasonably easy to load up the estimator and create an endpoint that you can post an image to and get the output you want.